# Individual Booleans are returning true, but when checking if both are true returns false

Tags: c#, boolean, unity-game-engine

So I have two booleans: `Player1Finish` and `Player2Finish`. They both turn to `true` when the players specifically enter a certain point. Everything in the code is working, and I tested it and had it print certain things if the booleans return `true` for test purposes:

```
if(Player1Finish == true){
    print("One");
}
if(Player2Finish == true){
    print("Two");
}
if(Player2Finish && Player1Finish){
    print("Both");
}
```

But these are the results I got: my console is printing out `"One"` and `"Two"` but not `"Both"`.  I'm seriously confused; what am I messing up?  I can't find any basic boolean questions that answer this, so if there is an answer I'd be more than happy to read it if you point me in the right direction.

There is nothing else in the code that is wrong besides this little loop, and it's the only thing keeping me from finishing.

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes, I have checked over every scrape of the code across a few scripts, made sure every input was correct. This is where I've narrowed my debugging down, and I'm honestly at a loss for what is going on.

Comment: Is this exactly your code or just a representation of what the logic does ? As written, in a single thread, if both your Player variables are true, the you should get all three outputs.

Comment: This is literally the exact code with the exception of I added some cuss words in the output out of frustration. The goal is not this, I just did this simple thing while I figured out what was going wrong.

Comment: What is your print function calling to produce the output ?

Comment: I'm using the unity editor, so "print" is just a shortcut to the debug log.

Comment: You may want to set Debug.AutoFlush = true and see what happens. Maybe the output is just not making it out of the buffer.

Comment: I got it to work, but I am a new member so it won't let me post it in an answer, I will try to remember to come back in 8 hours to post my solution, a small snippet of it is in the comment to Eric W's post.

Answer (score -1):

From what we see in your code snippet, you should be getting an output of "One", "Two", and "Both". Since you aren't, the only thing we can conclude is that something outside that snippet is affecting it.

If you add these lines of code directly before your code snippet, do you get all three outputs?

```
Player1Finish = true;
Player2Finish = true;
```

Comment: That is some pretty strange behavior. I don't see why is should matter, but does changing the code to this change the output? `if(Player1Finish){
    print("One");
}
if(Player2Finish ){ 
    print("Two");
}
if(Player2Finish && Player1Finish){
    print("Both");
}`

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting the same thing. I've tried a couple different formats or ways of writing it, it's always the same. For context, this is in a script for a videogame, being called as an update every frame. It checks to see if Player One or Two as finished, and if they have it prints out which one has, respectively, and if they both finish it ends the level. I got it to end when either one player ended or I can't get it to end at all, but I need it to end when BOTH finish, which is how I narrowed it down to this boolean issue.

Comment: Can someone tell me why my answer was marked down? Its not that big of a deal, but I'm so close to being able to comment on other peoples posts. Incidentally, this answer would have been in a comment if only I was allowed to post one.

Answer (score -2):

The following should work.

```
        if (Player1Finish == true && Player2Finish == true) {
            Console.Write("Both");
        } else if (Player1Finish == true) {
            Console.Write("One");
        } else {
            Console.Write("Two");
        }
```

Comment: That is a command in c#. this does not work in unity c# there you use print or  debug.log